# Visual Basic - No value given for one or more required parameters

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` which displays the contents of a table (with sql query). But whenever I run the code, it displays this error:

> No value given for one or more required parameters.

Where did it went wrong? The program ran without displaying any errors.

Here's the code for displaying in the `DataGridView`:

```
        Dim connString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\BSPDatabase.accdb"
        MyConn = New OleDbConnection
        MyConn.ConnectionString = connString
        ds = New DataSet
        tables = ds.Tables
        da = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [Transactions] where transMonth=" & monthCombobox.Text & "", MyConn)
        da.Fill(ds, "BSPDatabase") 'Change items to your database name
        Dim view As New DataView(tables(0))
        source1.DataSource = view
        TransactionsDataGridView.DataSource = view
```

Comment: do you have somewhere in the code above a `on error resume next` statement?

Comment: @psychicebola no, I don't.

Comment: What data type is transMonth? What is in monthCombobox.Text? Maybe you need something like `String.Format("Select * from [Transactions] where transMonth ='{0}'", monthCombobox.text)`

Comment: @Fruitbat transMonth is short text and monthCombobox is a combobox

Answer (score 0):

I think you are forming bad SQL. The value needs to be in quotes.

```
   da = New OleDbDataAdapter(String.Format("Select * from [Transactions] where transMonth ='{0}'", monthCombobox.text), MyConn)
```

Comment: Actually, the OP should use parameterized queries, not concatenate strings to create a statement. The current problem is just one of the issues raised by concatenation. SQL injection attacks, losing decimal or date values due to string formatting differences, bad performand and bad maintainability are just some of the problems